# Trying to test the CoordinatedShutdown process where my service uses a lifecycle stop hook to disconnect from a database

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a class that uses a ApplicationLifecycle hook:

```
class MyService @Inject() (lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {

    lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
        Future {
            db.close()
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to test that this hook gets called and my database connection gets closed.

I have this but it doesn't seem to work as I am able to connect to the database after this runs.

```
class MyServiceSpec extends .... {

    implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = builtInComponents.executionContext

   val service = new MyService(components.applicationLifecycle)


   "my test is here" in {
       Await.result(CoordinatedShutdown(components.actorSystem).run(CoordinatedShutdown.unknownReason), 5.seconds)

       whenReady(service.testConnection()) { r =>
        r.mustBe(false)
       }
   }

}
```

I am shutting down the actorSystem, so my lifecycle hooks should be called and my database connection should be closed no?

Comment: There are some missing parts in the code you show us that might prevent us to help you further. Does your spec extends `PlaySpec`, how is the test application built? Where does `db` comes from? What does `testConnection` does?

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes it extends `extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuiteWithComponents`.  Db is just injected, the point I am trying to understand is why the shutdown hook doesn't work?